# A problem regarding the rank of a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, symmetric-matrices

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ Given that $\operatorname A$ is an $m×m$ orthogonal matrix such that $\operatorname A$ is of the form :
                                 $$ \begin{pmatrix} 
          1/{\sqrt m} & 1/{\sqrt m} \cdots 1/{\sqrt m} \\
                 \operatorname P
                                \end{pmatrix}
                                  $$
 where $\operatorname P$ is an $(m-1)×m$ rectangular matrix . And let $\operatorname B$ be an $m×m$ symmetric matrix with rank $(m-1)$ and $\operatorname B1_m=0$ where ${1_m}^t=(1,1,....1)^t$ .

Then, show that :
$1)$ $\operatorname P^TP= \operatorname {I_m} - 1/m({1_m}{1_m}^t)$

$2)$ rank of $\operatorname { PBP^T} = m-1$ 
where $\operatorname I_m$ is the $m×m$ identity matrix .

$\mathbf {My \ approach} :$ Actually, I tried upto the portion that as $\operatorname A$ is orthogonal, then for any of its two columns $v_i$ and $v_j$, we have ${v_i}^tv_j = \delta_{ij}$ and then for any row vector ${p_i}^t$ of $\operatorname P$ ;

$$ {p_i}^tp_j = 
\begin{cases}
(1-1/m), & \text {for $i=j$} \\
  -1/m  ,   & \text{for  $i \neq j$}
\end{cases}  
$$ 
hence first part is done.

Now, as $\operatorname B$ is symmetric and $0$ is an eigenvalue appearing once with eigenvector ${1_m}$ and so $\operatorname { BP^TP} = B$ with $\operatorname { PBP^T}$ being orthogonally diagonalizable but I can't help myself to show that none of it's eigenvalues are $0 .$

Obs. : Sum of the entries of each row of $\operatorname B$ is $0 .$

A small hint is warmly appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Let $\mathbf{v}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\mathbf{1}_m$ and 
\begin{align}
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{v}^T\\
P
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
Since $A$ is orthogonal, then by block multiplication
\begin{align}
I=A^TA=
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{v} & 
P^T
\end{pmatrix}
 \begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{v}^T\\
P
\end{pmatrix}
=
\mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}^T+P^TP.
\end{align}

For 2), you will use the fact that
\begin{align}
\operatorname{rank}(AB)\leq \min\{\operatorname{rank}(A), \operatorname{rank}(B)\}.
\end{align}
Hence we see that
\begin{align}
\operatorname{rank}(PBP^T) \le \operatorname{rank}(B) =m-1.
\end{align}
Moreover, we have that
\begin{align}
\operatorname{rank}(P^TPBP^TP)\le \operatorname{rank}(PBP^T).
\end{align}
Since $P^TP$ is invertible from part (1), then it follows
\begin{align}
\operatorname{rank}(P^TPBP^TP)=\operatorname{rank}(B)=m-1.
\end{align}